# How to change the HTTP request timeout in CouchDB?

Tags: erlang, bigdata, couchdb, couchdb-futon

I am doing a bulk insert of large number of documents in CouchDB and when multiple bulk inserts are done in parallel, I'm getting 504 Gateway Timeout from CouchDB. I think the HTTP requests are getting timed out. How do I increase this timeout?

Comment: Need to provide way more detail...how are the bulk operations executing - In a browser? cUrl? Executed by <insert language here>?

Comment: I am performing bulk insert through erlang using couchbeam library. Insert 20000 docs in a bulk insert HTTP request. Its working fine when I send one request at a time. But Its failing when try to do more that one request concurrently.